# How to store mouse move position value in array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here I am trying to Store mouse position value in array so that my ball will move according to that array value.

Is there any better way to do this as I am stuck at the end of the project. Your help will be appreciated.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent (typeof(Ball))]
public class BallDragLaunch : MonoBehaviour {
    //MyScript
    //public float powePerPixel;
    public float maxPower;
    public float sensitivity;
    //private Vector3 touvhPos;
    private bool isRolling;
    private float rotation = 10f;
    //
    private Rigidbody rg;
    private Vector3 dragStart, dragFlick, dragEnd;
    private float startTime, endTime, flickTime;
    private Ball ball;
    public Rigidbody ballRigid;
    public float [] mousePositionX, mousePositionY;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ball = GetComponent<Ball> ();
        //MyScript
        isRolling = false;
        //ballRigid = this.ball;
    }

    public void MoveStart (float speed) {
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") > 0) {
            if (! ball.inPlay) {
                dragStart = Input.mousePosition;
                //transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(ball.transform.position.x + speed, ball.transform.position.x - speed, 0), -42.0f, 42.0f);

                float xPos = Mathf.Clamp (ball.transform.position.x + speed, -42.0f, 42.0f);

                float yPos = ball.transform.position.y;
                float zPos = ball.transform.position.z;
                ball.transform.position = new Vector3 (xPos, yPos, zPos);
                Debug.LogError("Right");
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") < 0) {
            if (! ball.inPlay) {
                dragStart = Input.mousePosition;
                //transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(ball.transform.position.x + speed, ball.transform.position.x - speed, 0), -42.0f, 42.0f);

                float xPos = Mathf.Clamp (ball.transform.position.x - speed, -42.0f, 42.0f);

                float yPos = ball.transform.position.y;
                float zPos = ball.transform.position.z;
                ball.transform.position = new Vector3 (xPos, yPos, zPos);
                Debug.LogError("Left");
            }
        }
    }

    public void DragStart () {
        if (! ball.inPlay) {
            // Capture time & position of drag start
            dragStart = Input.mousePosition;
            startTime = Time.time;
            Debug.LogError("Drag Start");
        }
    }

    public void DragEnd () {
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") < 0.2f) {

            if (! ball.inPlay) {
                // Launch the ball
                dragEnd = Input.mousePosition;
                endTime = Time.time;

                float dragDuration = endTime - startTime;
                float launchSpeedX = (dragEnd.x - dragStart.x) / dragDuration;
                float launchSpeedZ = (dragEnd.y - dragStart.y) / dragDuration;
                transform.Rotate (0, rotation, 0);
                Vector3 launchVelocity = new Vector3 (launchSpeedX * sensitivity, 0, launchSpeedZ);

                ball.Launch (launchVelocity);
                Debug.Log ("Drag End Ball Launch");
                Debug.LogError("Left Ball Movemet ");

            }
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") > 0.2f) {

            if (! ball.inPlay) {
                // Launch the ball
                dragEnd = Input.mousePosition;
                endTime = Time.time;

                float dragDuration = endTime - startTime;
                float launchSpeedX = (dragEnd.x - dragStart.x) / dragDuration;
                float launchSpeedZ = (dragEnd.y - dragStart.y) / dragDuration;
                transform.Rotate (0, rotation, 0);
                Vector3 launchVelocity = new Vector3 (launchSpeedX * sensitivity, 0, launchSpeedZ);

                ball.Launch (launchVelocity);
                Debug.Log ("Drag End Ball Launch");
                Debug.LogError("Right Ball Movemet ");

            }
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X") >= 0 ) {

            if (! ball.inPlay) {
                // Launch the ball
                dragEnd = Input.mousePosition;
                endTime = Time.time;

                float dragDuration = endTime - startTime;
                float launchSpeedX = (dragEnd.x - dragStart.x) / dragDuration;
                float launchSpeedZ = (dragEnd.y - dragStart.y) / dragDuration;
                transform.Rotate (0, rotation, 0);
                Vector3 launchVelocity = new Vector3 (launchSpeedX * sensitivity, 0, launchSpeedZ);

                ball.Launch (launchVelocity);
                //Debug.Log ("Drag End Ball Launch");
                Debug.LogError("Mid Ball Right Move");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the question/problem? Where does it not do what you'd like?

Comment: @TimBourguignon, he wants to save te position into an array, but does not really know its syntax. He essentially knows what he wants to achieve, but does not know how to do it. He probably tried to do it multiple times and failed. I have written an answer to him, describing how he can use arrays and suggesting that here he needs a Queue in my opinion, since he does not know the size of the array in advance, which will result in either too much allocated memory or exceptions due to index out of bounds.

Comment: That's pretty much what I understood as well, but the question doesn't make it easy to get it. There is a whole bunch of code that has absolutely nothing to do with the question (how the mouse positions are gathered) and no attempt at solving the question asked. Sorry to be a bit hard here, but I miss at least a comment somewhere saying something like "here I want to save the coordinates to use them later, here's what I tried".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in response to Lajos Arpad answer

I have to say use lists instead of arrays. They are so much better to work with, and you dont need to know how many variables will go into the list before hand.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[RequireComponent (typeof(Ball))]
public class BallDragLaunch : MonoBehaviour {
    //MyScript
    public List<Vector3> mousPositions;
```

in your code you can treat the list exactly the same way you would treat an array. To add mouse positions to the list simply write

```
mousePosition.Add(Input.mousePosition);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer your List concept is working well and its storing the mouse value also now what I want is my ball should move according to stored value. your help will be appropriated

Answer (score 0):

Your `ball` is moving in three dimensions and you use `Vector3` for them. On the other hand, you have two arrays of `float[]` called `mousePositionX` and `mousePositionY`, respectively. You could use a `Vector3[]` for that purpose. This is how you declare it:

```
public Vector3[] mousePositions;
```

If you know its size, which, for instance is `n`, then this is how you initialize it:

```
mousePositions = new Vector3[n];
```

and if you want to set its `i`'th value, then this is how you can do it:

```
mousePositions[i] = ball.transform.position;
```

Problems you need to solve:
- you need to know the size of the array before you initialize it
- you need to keep track of the first index where you have not put a valid position yet

I believe you will not know the size of the array in advance and you also do not want to always keep track of indexes. So I would use a [Queue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if I were you. Don't worry, it is not difficult. Try to work with the array solution first to have some success and when you see it works, create a **backup of your code** and try experimenting with a `Queue<Vector3>`. Believe me, it is worth it.